# Bibliography per chapter with continuous numbering

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

I would like to create a document with two chapters. After the first chapter there should be a bibliography. The next chapter should be able to reference items of the former chapter, but only show the new items in its bibliography, starting with the next number from the first bibliography.

Example:

> **Chapter 1 - The Fu**
>   Fu has been done by Bar [1]. Early versions ...
>   **Bibliography**
>   [1] Bar et. al., Doning the Fu
>
> **Chapter 2 - Compining Fu with Herp**
>   Doning Fu as described in [1]
>   neglects the advantages of Herp pointed out by Derp [2].
>   Consequently ....
>   **Bibliography**
>   [2] Derp et. al., The Advantages of Using Herp

Please not too much discussion about if that is a friendly-to-use idea, it is not my own demand :)

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58181

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use of `refsegment` will continue label numbering for you. To print a reference in just one sub-bibliography (and completely frustrate most readers), you can track the continuation number for each `refsegment` and skip any items whose label is less than that number.

In the example below the default sorting scheme is used, but it could be changed. To get the label numbers right, this approach will require a couple additional passes with `latex`. `biblatex` gives you a message whenever another pass is needed.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[sorting=none,style=numeric,refsegment=chapter,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\defbibheading{subbibliography}{%
  \section*{Bibliography}}

\makeatletter

% Overall entry counter
\csnumgdef{blx@entrycount}{0}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \csnumgdef{blx@entrycount}{\csuse{blx@entrycount}+1}}

% Continued from this label number
\appto{\newrefsegment}{%
  \csnumgdef{blx@entrycount@\the\c@refsegment}{\csuse{blx@entrycount}+1}}

% Skip entries with label numbers less than the continued number
\defbibcheck{onlynew}{%
  \ifnumless{\thefield{labelnumber}}{\csuse{blx@entrycount@\the\c@refsegment}}
    {\skipentry}
    {}}

\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{companion,
  author = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
  title = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location = {Reading, Mass.},
  date = {1994}}
@Article{gillies,
  author = {Gillies, Alexander},
  title = {Herder and the Preparation of Goethe's Idea of World Literature},
  journaltitle = {Publications of the English Goethe Society},
  volume = {9},
  date = {1933},
  pages = {46--67}}
@Article{bertram,
  author = {Bertram, Aaron and Wentworth, Richard},
  title = {Gromov invariants for holomorphic maps on Riemann surfaces},
  journaltitle = {J.~Amer. Math. Soc.},
  volume = {9},
  number = {2},
  date = {1996},
  pages = {529--571}}
@Book{poetics,
  author = {Aristotle},
  editor = {Lucas, D. W.},
  title = {Poetics},
  series = {Clarendon Aristotle},
  publisher = {Clarendon Press},
  location = {Oxford},
  date = {1968}}
@Book{rhetoric,
  author = {Aristotle},
  editor = {Cope, Edward Meredith},
  commentator = {Cope, Edward Meredith},
  title = {The Rhetoric of Aristotle with a commentary by the late Edward Meredith Cope},
  volumes = {3},
  publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
  date = {1877}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
  \cites{companion}{rhetoric}
  \printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,check=onlynew,heading=subbibliography]
\chapter{Second}
  \cites{companion}{bertram}{poetics}
  \printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,check=onlynew,heading=subbibliography]
\chapter{Third}
  \cites{companion}{bertram}{gillies}{rhetoric}
  \printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,check=onlynew,heading=subbibliography]
\end{document}
```

Results for the first chapter:

[image]

And the second:

[image]

And the third:

[image]

Comment: I've edited to add `sorting=none` to the biblatex option, necessary for this to work on TexLive 2013. It would be nice to get an example that did not rely on chapters. Simply each time `\printbibliography` is called, only new bib items are printed. I'm working on that change, but I am not proficient in TeX.

Answer (score 1):

Since the code in the accepted answer stopped working with more recent versions of `biblatex` (as discussed in [biblatex: continuous reference numbering without duplication](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/517199/35864)), here is an updated version that should work again.

The answer is copied verbatim from my answer to the linked question.

---

I suggest the following hopefully more stable solution. For each entry it records the first `refsegment` in which it was cited. The filter `onlynew` then only needs to check if this `refsegment` has a number smaller than the current `refsegment`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \ifcsundef{blx@entry@refsegment@\the\c@refsection @\thefield{entrykey}}
    {\csnumgdef{blx@entry@refsegment@\the\c@refsection @\thefield{entrykey}}{\the\c@refsegment}}
    {}}
\defbibcheck{onlynew}{%
  \ifnumless{0\csuse{blx@entry@refsegment@\the\c@refsection @\thefield{entrykey}}}{\the\c@refsegment}
    {\skipentry}
    {}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\newrefsegment
refsegment \therefsegment:
\cite{sigfridsson,worman}
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,check=onlynew]

\newrefsegment
refsegment \therefsegment:
\cite{sigfridsson,geer,nussbaum}
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,check=onlynew]

\newrefsegment
refsegment \therefsegment:
\cite{sigfridsson,geer,pines,worman}
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,check=onlynew]
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography with only new entries: 1,2//3,4//5]

---

Here is a solution that also works for `\nocite`. Since there is no `\AtEveryCitekey`-equivalent for `\nocite` we have to hook into internal commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\def\blx@citation@entry#1#2{%
  \blx@bibreq{#1}%
  \ifinlist{#1}\blx@cites
    {}
    {\listgadd{\blx@cites}{#1}}%
  \blx@auxwrite\@mainaux{}{\string\abx@aux@cite{#1}}%
  \ifinlistcs{#1}{blx@segm@\the\c@refsection @\the\c@refsegment}
    {}
    {\listcsgadd{blx@segm@\the\c@refsection @\the\c@refsegment}{#1}}%
  \blx@auxwrite\@mainaux{}{\string\abx@aux@segm{\the\c@refsection}%
                                               {\the\c@refsegment}%
                                               {\detokenize{#1}}}%
  \ifcsundef{blx@entry@refsegment@\the\c@refsection @#1}
    {\csnumgdef{blx@entry@refsegment@\the\c@refsection @#1}{\the\c@refsegment}}
    {}%
  \blx@ifdata{#1}
    {}
    {\ifcsdef{blx@miss@\the\c@refsection}
       {\ifinlistcs{#1}{blx@miss@\the\c@refsection}
          {}
          {\blx@logreq@active{#2{#1}}}}
       {\blx@logreq@active{#2{#1}}}}}

\defbibcheck{onlynew}{%
  \ifnumless{0\csuse{blx@entry@refsegment@\the\c@refsection @\thefield{entrykey}}}{\the\c@refsegment}
    {\skipentry}
    {}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\newrefsegment
refsegment \therefsegment:
\cite{sigfridsson,worman}
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,check=onlynew]

\newrefsegment
refsegment \therefsegment:
\cite{sigfridsson,geer,nussbaum}\nocite{knuth:ct:a}
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,check=onlynew]

\newrefsegment
refsegment \therefsegment:
\cite{sigfridsson,geer,pines,worman}\nocite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,check=onlynew]
\end{document}
```