# Distributing bibliographies to sections -- without duplication, and using chapterbib

Tags: subdividing, chapterbib

Currently I use the chapterbib package, together with natbib with option "numbers", and this for a grant-proposal document with a CV-section and a Case-section. Each of these two chapters needs a bibliography at its end (thus using chapterbib), but due to page-restrictions the second bibliography should just continue the first one, not duplicating the entries from the first one.

This is in principal the same question as asked in
[Bibliography sections without duplicate entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58181/bibliography-sections-without-duplicate-entries)
and it has even the same motivation, as discussed there in the comments to the second answer. Similarly we have
[Multiple reference lists using biblatex: how to remove duplicated entries?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245971/multiple-reference-lists-using-biblatex-how-to-remove-duplicated-entries)
again using refsegment.

However my question is whether this can be achieved by the nice machinery of chapterbib? Then I (and others) needed not to change the whole setting. Best would be just to add something to the second include-file, which removes the duplicated entries, and lets the ref-count continue where the first bibliography stops. (So that in effect we have one bibliography, with continuous citation-numbers, only split into two parts.)

It seems that this is actually not possible with chapterbib, but perhaps there is a hack?

If there is no such hack, then perhaps the easiest thing is to initially just use a single bibliography for the whole document, and once everything is finished, then manually take the thebiblibiography-items, find the splitting point, and partition them into two parts.

To be specific, the code structure is as follows:

Main.tex:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,11pt]{article}
\pagestyle{headings}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage{savetrees}

\begin{document}
\onecolumn
\title{Grant Proposal}
% Address
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
{\large
\tableofcontents
}
\newpage

\setlength{\textwidth}{14.8cm}
\include{Part1}
\newpage
\include{Part2}

\end{document}
```

Part1.tex:

```
\twocolumn
\setcounter{page}{1}
\section{Track Record}
{\small
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{Bibfile}
}
```

Part2.tex:

```
\section{Research Proposal}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{Bibfile}
```

Comment: I think the approach you outline should work. You would have to manually adjust the numbering of the second bibliography though. This is addressed here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289457/bibliography-starting-from-any-number

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you add a small example to play with?

Comment: I just added the outline structure. Hope that helps.