# Continuous numbering of references

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I'm using `\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}` to format my references with `\footcite{}` for the in text references, while also separating my chapters into individual tex files by using `\include{ChapterName}` in the main tex document.

However, I find that the footnotes seem to reset whever I start a new chapter; references in the first chapter are 1, 2, 3... but in the second chapter it also starts again from 1. I would like the numbering to be continuous, resuming from the last number in the previous chapter.

The other aspects I'm okay with, such as a shortened reference when referring to a reference that was referred to earlier in the document, and ibid when referring to the same reference again on the same page. Just the numbering should be continuous.

What would I need to add to the preamble for it to work like this?

Edit: My question was thought to be a duplicate of [Bibliography per chapter with continuous numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26331/bibliography-per-chapter-with-continuous-numbering) . Instead, my question is the opposite - I want numbering to be continuous throughout the whole report, with chapters resuming the numbering from the previous chapter.

Edit 2: Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{MastersDoctoralThesis}
\usepackage{style=verbose-ibid,backend=bibtex}[biblatex]
\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}
\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\include{Chapter1}
\include{Chapter2}
\end{document}
```

The auxillary file contents are as follows:

Bibliography.bib:

```
@Article{gillies,
  author = {Gillies, Alexander},
  title = {Herder and the Preparation of Goethe's Idea of World Literature},
  journaltitle = {Publications of the English Goethe Society},
  volume = {9},
  date = {1933},
  pages = {46--67}}
@Article{bertram,
  author = {Bertram, Aaron and Wentworth, Richard},
  title = {Gromov invariants for holomorphic maps on Riemann surfaces},
  journaltitle = {J.~Amer. Math. Soc.},
  volume = {9},
  number = {2},
  date = {1996},
  pages = {529--571}}
```

Chapter1.tex:

```
Sample text\footcite{gillies}.
```

Chapter2.tex:

```
Some more\footcite{gillies} sample\footcite{bertram} text.
```

Comment: I've tried addding the code under the `% Overall entry counter, % Continued from this label number, % Skip entries with label numbers less than the continued number` but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: What about the options given to `\usepackage{biblatex}` ?

Comment: Nope, doesn't make any difference - I need to use `verbose-ibid` formatting so I didn't change the `style=` part from `verbose-ibid` to `numerical`.

Comment: can you give a MWE ?

Comment: Can you please add a link to this `MastersDoctoralThesis` class you are using? It is not part of a standard latex distribution.

Comment: It follows the standard Report format, but here's a link:
http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis

Comment: Does this work: `\usepackage{chngcntr} \counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}`? I don't have this document class and I try not to use these (implicitly?) [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/)-unfriendly classes....

Comment: Glad it works. Looks like a duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10448/8528