# Separate continuous per-chapter bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, thesis

I am using LaTeX with the Masters/Doctoral Thesis Template ([latextemplates.com](http://www.latextemplates.com/)) for writing my Thesis.

Let us suppose that the author has published a few papers on each chapter. Our University has the requirement to include a list of those papers at the end of each chapter. The items need to be numbered as [A1], [A2], etc., and the numeration to be continued in each chapter.

Then, at the end of the Thesis, a full list of all authored publications has to be places, followed by a list of all references in the Thesis.

I have some modest experience with LaTeX and did not manage to accomplish this by merely looking through the various related posts online. I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26331/bibliography-per-chapter-with-continuous-numbering), but the accepted solution seemed a tad unclear to me.

Hence, I would like to ask this as a question here.

Here is how a sample output should look like:

> 1 Aster
>
> Reference [A1,A2] states that in [ 1],
>
> Per-chapter Author References
>
> [A1] CTAN. The Comprehensive TeX Archive Network. 2006. url: http : /
>   / www.ctan.org (visited on 10/01/2006).
>
> [A2] Emma Sigfridsson and Ulf
>   Ryde. “Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the
>   electrostatic potential and moments”. In: Jour- nal of Computational
>   Chemistry 19.4 (1998), pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/
>   (SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.
>
> 2 Begonia
>
> Reference [A2,A3] states that in [ 2],...
>
> Per-chapter Author References
>
> [A2] Emma Sigfridsson and Ulf Ryde. “Comparison of methods for
>   deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments”.
>   In: Jour- nal of Computational Chemistry 19.4 (1998), pp. 377–395.
>   doi: 10.1002/ (SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.
>
> [A3] Aristotle. Physics. Trans. by P. H. Wicksteed and F. M. Cornford.
>   New York: G. P. Putnam, 1929.
>
> 3 Cichorium
>
> Reference [A3,A4] states that in [ 3],...
>
> Per-chapter Author References
>
> [A3] Aristotle. Physics. Trans. by P. H. Wicksteed and F. M. Cornford.
>   New York: G. P. Putnam, 1929.
>
> [A4] John C. Baez and Aaron D. Lauda.
>   Higher-Dimensional Algebra V: 2- Groups. Version 3. Oct. 27, 2004.
>   arXiv: math/0307200v3.
>
> Author References
>
> [A1] CTAN. The Comprehensive TeX Archive Network. 2006. url: http : /
>   / www.ctan.org (visited on 10/01/2006).
>
> [A2] Emma Sigfridsson and Ulf
>   Ryde. “Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the
>   electrostatic potential and moments”. In: Jour- nal of Computational
>   Chemistry 19.4 (1998), pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/
>   (SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.
>
> [A3] Aristotle. Physics. Trans. by P. H. Wicksteed and F. M. Cornford. New York: G. P. Putnam, 1929.
>
> [A4] John C. Baez and Aaron D. Lauda. Higher-Dimensional
>   Algebra V: 2- Groups. Version 3. Oct. 27, 2004. arXiv: math/0307200v3.
>
> References (excluding author references)
>
> [ 1] A. Author. Alpha, 2001.
>
> [ 2] Nicolas Markey. Tame the BeaST. The B
>   to X of BibTeX. Version 1.3. Oct. 16, 2005. url:
>   http://mirror.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ ttb_en.pdf (visited
>   on 10/01/2006).
>
> [ 3] Gary Westfahl. “The True Frontier. Confronting and
>   Avoiding the Realities of Space in American Science Fiction Films”.
>   In: Space and Beyond. The Frontier Theme in Science Fiction. Ed. by
>   Gary Westfahl. Westport, Conn. and London: Greenwood, 2000, pp. 55–65.

And here is a MWE, taken from [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,defernumbers=true,refsection=section]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\section{Aster}
\cite{ctan,sigfridsson} and some text
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,resetnumbers=false]
\section{Begonia}
\cite{aristotle:physics,markey}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,resetnumbers=false]
\section{Cichorium}
\cite{westfahl:space,baez/online}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,resetnumbers=false]
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you need `refsegment`s and not `refsection`s since you want to be able to use the same entry in the entire document and have it referred by the same name throughout. The per-section bibliographies can be filtered with the `segment` key.

Due to the split nature of the author bibliography it is surprisingly difficult to get the `labelprefix` right. Usually `labelprefix` implies `resetnumbers`, but we don't want that here, so we have to fake it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, defernumbers=true, sorting=none, refsegment=section]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\define@key{blx@bib1}{fakeresetnums}[]{\toggletrue{blx@resetnumsexplicit}}
\define@key{blx@bib2}{fakeresetnums}[]{\toggletrue{blx@resetnumsexplicit}}
\makeatother


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  date    = {1980},
  keywords = {author},
}
@book{appleby:2,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service II},
  date    = {1981},
  keywords = {author},
}
@book{appleby:3,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service III},
  date    = {1981},
  keywords = {author},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{Aster}
\cite{ctan,sigfridsson,appleby} and some text
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=A]
\printbibliography[fakeresetnums, heading=subbibliography, segment=\therefsegment, keyword=author, title={Author Bibliography}]

\section{Begonia}
\cite{aristotle:physics,markey,appleby:2}
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=A]
\printbibliography[fakeresetnums, heading=subbibliography, segment=\therefsegment, keyword=author, title={Author Bibliography}]

\section{Cichorium}
\cite{westfahl:space,baez/online,appleby,appleby:3}
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=A]
\printbibliography[fakeresetnums, heading=subbibliography, segment=\therefsegment, keyword=author, title={Author Bibliography}]


\printbibliography[keyword=author, title={Author References}]
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=]
\printbibliography[notkeyword=author, title={References}]
\end{document}
```

[image: Split bibliography similar to the desiderata outlined in the question.]

Comment: Dear moewe, many thanks for all your insightful posts in this community! Your answer will be of huge help for me during the preparation of my Thesis and thanks to it, the structure will be much more clear and conforming to the local guidelines.

Comment: Sorry for the double comment, I could not edit the first one.
An additional question has arisen. Would there be any means to denote that the first `bib` file (`\jobname.bib`) contains only authored references while the second (`biblatex-examples.bib`) is filled with the remaining sources?
This way, we could omit the `keyword` key in `\printbibliography` which would make it much easier to work with exported bibliography, e.g. from Zotero, without any manual (or programmatic) intervention of the bib files to add the desired keyword. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ndandanov https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35279/35864 describes several methods to automatically produce a label based on the `.bib` file. You'll be interested in the `\DeclareSourcemap` at the end of PLK's answer.