# biblatex: continuous reference numbering without duplication

Tags: biblatex

I am using the `refsegment` feature of `biblatex` to assemble multiple bibliographies within the same document.  I would like to have continuous reference numbering across the `refsegment`s (i.e., if the last new reference of `refsegment` N is assigned the number `i`, then the first new reference of `refsegment` N+1 will be assigned the number `i+1`).  I would also like to avoid duplication of already-cited references in the sub-bibliographies.  That is to say, while a given reference may be cited in more than one `refsegment`, it should be included only in the sub-bibliography for the `refsegment` in which it first occurs.  Here is a simple example:

```
refsegment #1:
The quick brown fox [1] jumps over the lazy dog [2].
Bibliography:
   [1] Fox reference.
   [2] Dog reference.

refsegment #2:
The lazy dog [2] was busy doing nothing [3].
Bibliography:
   [3] Reference on nothing.
```

Note that reference #2 was not included in the second bibliography even though it was cited in the second `refsegment` because it had already been included in the first bibliography.

[This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26356/10127) proposed a solution to this problem, namely the `onlynew` bibliographic check, which suppresses repeated bibliographic items.  The proposed solution keeps a running tally of bibliographic items (stored in the control sequence `\blx@entrycount`) and records the next reference number at the start of each `refsegment` (in the control sequence `\blx@entrycount@\the\c@refsegment`).  Then, if the number assigned to a given bibliographic item (`\thefield{labelnumber}`) is less than (`\ifnumless{}`) the latter quantity, it is skipped in the bibliography (since it has already been referenced).  However, upon compilation (TeX Live 2019), all citations are assigned the number zero, the bibliographies are empty, and the following warning is emitted:

```
LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line <n>
```

The below example reproduces the problem.  What changes are needed to fix the code in the MWE?

---

**MWE** (adapted from linked post):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\makeatletter
% Overall entry counter
\csnumgdef{blx@entrycount}{0}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \csnumgdef{blx@entrycount}{\csuse{blx@entrycount}+1}}

% Continued from this label number
\appto{\newrefsegment}{%
  \csnumgdef{blx@entrycount@\the\c@refsegment}{\csuse{blx@entrycount}+1}}

% Skip entries with label numbers less than the continued number
\defbibcheck{onlynew}{%
  \ifnumless{\thefield{labelnumber}}{\csuse{blx@entrycount@\the\c@refsegment}}
    {\skipentry}
    {}}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{companion,
  author = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
  title = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location = {Reading, Mass.},
  date = {1994}}
@Article{gillies,
  author = {Gillies, Alexander},
  title = {Herder and the Preparation of Goethe's Idea of World Literature},
  journaltitle = {Publications of the English Goethe Society},
  volume = {9},
  date = {1933},
  pages = {46--67}}
@Article{bertram,
  author = {Bertram, Aaron and Wentworth, Richard},
  title = {Gromov invariants for holomorphic maps on Riemann surfaces},
  journaltitle = {J.~Amer. Math. Soc.},
  volume = {9},
  number = {2},
  date = {1996},
  pages = {529--571}}
@Book{poetics,
  author = {Aristotle},
  editor = {Lucas, D. W.},
  title = {Poetics},
  series = {Clarendon Aristotle},
  publisher = {Clarendon Press},
  location = {Oxford},
  date = {1968}}
@Book{rhetoric,
  author = {Aristotle},
  editor = {Cope, Edward Meredith},
  commentator = {Cope, Edward Meredith},
  title = {The Rhetoric of Aristotle with a commentary by the late Edward Meredith Cope},
  volumes = {3},
  publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
  date = {1877}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\newrefsegment
refsegment \therefsegment:
\cite{companion,rhetoric}
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,check=onlynew]

\newrefsegment
refsegment \therefsegment:
\cite{companion,bertram,poetics}
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,check=onlynew]

\newrefsegment
refsegment \therefsegment:
\cite{companion,bertram,gillies,rhetoric}
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,check=onlynew]

\end{document}
```

Compilation: pdflatex && biber && pdflatex && pdflatex

Output:

[image]

Comment: Basically this bib system means that if in segment N there is a cite, the reader has to search for the bib entry in N reference sections starting probably on N different pages - sounds like a very effective way to discourage a reader to ever check a source.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I agree.  This is the requirement I face, however.

Comment: Well my point of view is that if someone requires such nonsense they should pay for the implementation of their whims instead of asking the volonteers to do it for free.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I think you misunderstand. The asker and requirer are separate; for all the requirer cares, this can be done in Microsoft Word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quoted answer is over eight years old and some internal things have changed since then. I can't be absolutely sure, but the main issue seems to be the `defernumbers` option. With that all `labelnumber`s are initially set to 0 and non-zero numbers are only assigned once an entry was printed in a bibliography. Unfortunately, the test `\ifnumless{\thefield{labelnumber}}{\csuse{blx@entrycount@\the\c@refsegment}}` will always be true if `labelnumber` is 0, so all entries are skipped in each bibliography, which means that the bibliographies stay empty and thus that `blx@entrycount` is never increased.

I suggest the following hopefully more stable solution. For each entry it records the first `refsegment` in which it was cited. The filter `onlynew` then only needs to check if this `refsegment` has a number smaller than the current `refsegment`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \ifcsundef{blx@entry@refsegment@\the\c@refsection @\thefield{entrykey}}
    {\csnumgdef{blx@entry@refsegment@\the\c@refsection @\thefield{entrykey}}{\the\c@refsegment}}
    {}}
\defbibcheck{onlynew}{%
  \ifnumless{0\csuse{blx@entry@refsegment@\the\c@refsection @\thefield{entrykey}}}{\the\c@refsegment}
    {\skipentry}
    {}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\newrefsegment
refsegment \therefsegment:
\cite{sigfridsson,worman}
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,check=onlynew]

\newrefsegment
refsegment \therefsegment:
\cite{sigfridsson,geer,nussbaum}
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,check=onlynew]

\newrefsegment
refsegment \therefsegment:
\cite{sigfridsson,geer,pines,worman}
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,check=onlynew]
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography with only new entries: 1,2//3,4//5]

---

Here is a solution that also works for `\nocite`. The hook `\AtEveryEntrykey` was added in `biblatex` 3.15 (see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/934). If you are using an older version of `biblatex`, please refer to the edit history for a workaround.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\AtEveryEntrykey{%
  \ifcsundef{blx@entry@refsegment@\the\c@refsection @#1}
    {\csnumgdef{blx@entry@refsegment@\the\c@refsection @#1}{\the\c@refsegment}}
    {}}
  {}{}

\defbibcheck{onlynew}{%
  \ifnumless{0\csuse{blx@entry@refsegment@\the\c@refsection @\thefield{entrykey}}}{\the\c@refsegment}
    {\skipentry}
    {}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\newrefsegment
refsegment \therefsegment:
\cite{sigfridsson,worman}
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,check=onlynew]

\newrefsegment
refsegment \therefsegment:
\cite{sigfridsson,geer,nussbaum}\nocite{knuth:ct:a}
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,check=onlynew]

\newrefsegment
refsegment \therefsegment:
\cite{sigfridsson,geer,pines,worman}\nocite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,check=onlynew]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks moewe, that works well.  I'm wondering if you could clarify a few minor points:  (1) Is `blx@entry@refsegment@\the\c@refsection @\thefield{entrykey}` a single control sequence (with a space in the middle)?  (2) Is `entrykey` the .bib file entry key (e.g., `sigfridsson`)?  Finally, (3) does contatenation of `0` and `\csuse{blx@entry@refsegment@\the\c@refsection @\thefield{entrykey}` make the first argument of `\ifnumless` zero if the control sequence specified by `\csuse{}` is undefined?

Comment: @user001 (1) In `..cs..` macros `blx@entry@refsegment@\the\c@refsection @\thefield{entrykey}` gets expanded before forming the control sequence name, so this becomes for example `blx@entry@refsegment@0@sigfridsson` for `sigfridsson` in refsection 0, the space after `\c@refsection` is swallowed by the usual TeX rules (for more on `...cs...` macros see also Phelype's explanations to your recent question https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/517205/35864). (2) Yes, within `biblatex` we can access the entry key with `\thefield{entrykey}`. (3) Yes.

Comment: Many thanks for clarifying.

Comment: One further question: this does not appear to work with `\nocite` (e.g., try adding `\nocite{aksin}` after `\cite{sigfridsson,worman}`).  Is there a simple workaround?  (I can open a new question if the workaround is not straightforward.)

Comment: @user001 I'll look into it. But not tonight.

Comment: Sure, thanks, and if it looks to be too much trouble, let me know and I'll open a new question.

Comment: @user001 See the updated answer, please.

Comment: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/934

Comment: Thanks for the solution as well as the enhancement request. That's quite a bit more involved than the original answer.  I notice that it gives only zeros if the option `sorting=none` is passed to `biblatex` -- is that expected?

Comment: Does it also give all zeros if you invoke the option `sorting=none`?  If so, should I open a new question pertaining to this issue? Thanks.

Comment: @user001 `sorting=none` works for me in both MWEs. Remember that thanks to `defenumbers=true` you need to run LaTeX twice after Biber is run. So the minimal compilation sequence after changes to the bibliography or citations is LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX. If additional runs are needed this should be logged in the `.log` file. If you still can't get things going, please ask a new question with MWE, explain exactly how you compile it and include `.log` and `.blg` files.

Comment: Thanks, I opened a [new thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/517893/10127). I cannot avoid the "There were undefined references" warning, despite running `biber` and `pdflatex` many times.

Comment: @moewe right, I moved it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks!