# what does csnumgdef do?

Tags: macros, etoolbox

What does `\csnumgdef` do?  From code examples, it appears to take two arguments, and one is led to believe that it defines a number `var` and assigns to it the value `val`, as in `\csnumgdef{var}{val}`.  If `var` is being used as a simple counter, what are the advantages/disadvantages of this syntax over something like:

```
\newcounter{var}
\setcounter{var}{val}
```

Lastly, what is the etymology of `csnumgdef`, in particular the `cs` and the `g`?  I have noticed other commands that appear to be in the `cs` family, such as `\csname`, `\csuse`, and `\csdef`, but am not familiar with what unites them.

Comment: What package is `\csnumgdef` from? (`cs` stands for "control sequence". `\csname`, `\csnumgdef`, `\documentclass`, `\begin`, are all examples of control sequences. `g` possibly means "global", for a global assignment)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: I believe it's not part of any package, but rather is part of the TeX core.  For example, it is used [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26356/10127), which uses only two packages (biblatex, filecontents), neither of which mentions `csnumgdef` in their manuals.  Thanks for the explanation of `cs` and `g`.

Comment: no it is a macro from a package not anything built in to tex

Comment: From the three you mentioned (`\csname`, `\csuse`, and `\csdef`), only `\csname` is a TeX primitive (`\csname something\endcsname` expands to `\something`). The other two (and possibly more `\cs<whatever>` are macros which (usually) use `\csname` to make a control sequence of the argument. `\csuse{<arg>}` is just `\csname <arg>\endcsname`. `\csdef{<name>}{<definition>}` does `\def\<name>{<definition>}`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: Thanks, your remarks on which of these `cs` commands are macros and which are TeX primitives was most helpful.

Comment: One more note: If you are not sure if something is a TeX primitive or a macro, you can use `\show`. If you do `\show\csname`, TeX will print `> \csname=\csname` to the terminal, meaning it's a primitive. If you do `\show\csdef`, TeX will print: `> \csdef=\protected macro: #1->\expandafter \def \csname #1\endcsname`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: Thanks, I wasn't aware of `\show`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\csnumgdef`, from the `etoolbox` package (for you, loaded by `biblatex`) is defined as:

```latex
\newrobustcmd*{\csnumgdef}[1]{%
  \expandafter\numgdef\csname#1\endcsname}
```

in terms of `\numgdef` which, in turn, is defined as:

```latex
\newrobustcmd*{\numgdef}[2]{%
  \ifundef#1{\let#1\z@}{}%
  \xdef#1{\the\numexpr#2}}
```

Let's walk an example step by step. Suppose you do `\csnumgdef{foo}{1+1}`. First, `\csnumgdef` takes one argument, `foo`, and does (the `{1+1}` is still there from the previous step, untouched):

```latex
\expandafter\numgdef\csname foo\endcsname{1+1}
```

The `\expandafter` skips over `\numgdef` and expands `\csname`. `\csname` builds a control sequence (thus the `cs` in the name of `\csnumgdef`) out of everything until the matching `\endcsname`, which is the argument `foo`. This becomes:

```latex
\numgdef\foo{1+1}
```

so you can conclude that `\csnumgdef{foo}` and `\numgdef\foo` are equivalent.

Now `\numgdef` expands, grabbing two arguments, `\foo` and `1+1`:

```latex
\ifundef\foo{\let\foo\z@}{}%
\xdef\foo{\the\numexpr 1+1}
```

The `\ifundef` test checks if `\foo` is undefined, and does `\let\foo\z@` if so, otherwise it does nothing.

Now for the good part: `\xdef` is equivalent to `\global\edef` (and now you see that the `g` in `(cs)numgdef` stands for `\global`), which will make a global assignment, and `\edef` will expand everything inside the definition. It will expand [`\the`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38680/134574), which will trigger `\numexpr`. `\numexpr` will then evaluate the integer expression following it (`1+1`) and leave the result there. After the expansion, you have (sort of):

```latex
\global\def\foo{2}
```

and now things go as usual, and now `\foo` expands to `2`.

---

In short, `\csnumgdef{<name>}{<intexpr>}` will evaluate the integer expression `<intexpr>` and will store it in `\<name>`. The version without `cs` in the name takes a control sequence as argument (as opposed to a control sequence name): `\numgdef\<name>{<intexpr>}`, and the version without `g` does a local assignment.

---

These naming conventions are useful (especially when followed correctly ;-) because you don't need to look up the definition of some command to find ouy what it does. If you know that `\numdef\foo{1+1}` does, then it's not hard to deduce what `\csnumdef` or `\numgdef` do (given, of course, you know these conventions).

`expl3`'s conventions define that a function that contains `set` in its name does an assignment (much like the `def` in `\numdef`). If the function is `gset` then such assignment is global. Knowing that, it's fairly easy to guess what `\int_set:Nn` do: it's (almost<sup>1</sup>) the same as `\numdef` :-)
If you know that, then `\int_gset:Nn` is easy.

But what about the `cs` version, you ask. This one is denoted in the argument specification. Instead of a single `N`ormal argument, the argument is a `c`sname. `\int_set:cn` (equivalent of `\csnumdef`) and `\int_gset:cn` (equivalent of `\csnumgdef`) do exactly that :-)

<sup>1</sup> `\numdef` stores the number in a macro, while `\int_set:Nn` stores it in a count register.

Comment: The walkthrough and especially the comparison between `\csnumgdef{foo}{val}` and `\numgdef\foo{val}` were most illuminating.

Comment: @user001 Glad it helped :-) See the note I added a note on naming conventions

Comment: Let's mention that `\let#1\z@` within the definition of `\numgdef` makes it possible to do `\csnumgdef{foo}{\csuse{foo}+1}` without defining/initializing `\foo` as in case `\foo` is undefined, this will define/initialize `\foo` to be equal to `0`.

Comment: A model answer. Bravo!

Answer (score 6):

`\csnumgdef` is defined within the [`etoolbox` package](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox). This package "is a toolbox of programming tools geared primarily towards LaTeX class and package authors. It provides LaTeX frontends to some of the new primitives provided by e-TeX as well as some generic tools which are not related to e-TeX but match the profile of this package." (from the [`etoolbox` documentation](//texdoc.net/pkf/etoolbox).

The `cs`, `g` and `def` nomenclature is used through the documentation, roughly defined as

- `cs` = `<csname>`
- `g`  = `g`lobal
- `def` = `\def`

Another interpretation is that `gdef` is similar to `\gdef` or `\global\def` (or, possible `\xdef` - an e`x`panded version of `\gdef`).

---

In some contexts, its convenient to just consider the control sequence name (say, `foo`), rather than the control sequence itself (say, `\foo`). For example, perhaps you want to define an auxiliary control sequence that should accompany some definition and, for the sake of coding, you use the same basic definition. Here's an example:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\foo}{foo}
\newcommand{\foo@bar}{bar}
\newcommand{\print}[1]{\csname #1\endcsname: \csname #1@bar\endcsname}
\makeatother

\print{foo}
```

which prints

> foo: bar

It's easy to pass `foo` to `\print` and then have access to `\foo@bar`. However, if you have passed `\foo` to `\print`, you'd have to remove the backslash `\` in order to string add the suffix `@bar` and have access to `\foo@bar`. So, depending on the user (package author), it might be more convenient to work with control sequence names rather than the control sequences themselves.

---

`etoolbox` explicitly defines some of these functions in order to force a specific use. `\csnumgdef{<var>}{<val>}` is not the same a

```
\newcounter{<var>}
\setcounter{<var>}{<val>}
```

since `<var>` in `\csnumgdef` is not a counter. Instead, it's a regular control sequence. However, since `<val>` is evaluated using `\numexpr`, only arguments that are valid in that context is accepted. So, it may seem similar to using a counter, but internally it's different. Since it uses `\numexpr`, you can do something like `\csnumgdef{foo}{5+2}` and have `7` stored in `\foo`. You don't need `\thefoo` to print the number if you'd gone the route of defining a counter.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the nomenclature as well as for clarifying that the first argument of `csnumgdef` is a control sequence name rather than a variable.